# replace names of all directiories and files in PS

Tags: powershell, renaming

I want to replace all space characters into "_" in names of all subfolders and files.
Unfortunately when I type:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item $_ $_.replace(" ","_") }
```

Error message:

> Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different. At line:1
>   char:60
>   + Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item <<<<  $_ $*.replace(" ","*") }
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (PATH_HERE) [Rename-Item], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

How I should improve this short code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't use the Name switch, it outputs only the names of the objects, not their full path. Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | `
   Where-Object {$_.Name -match ' '} | `
     Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ' ','_' }
```

Comment: Nice. Might want to include Where-Object {$_.Attributes -notmatch 'Directory' } as an additional filter. You can't rename a directory while you're iterating through it.

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn another trick is to sort the collection by the FullName in descending order.  This forces the script to handle all of the child items in a directory before modifying the directory itself.

Comment: Thank you!  I've referred to your answer on a couple other related pages.  You are the only one to get around the two most common issues.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Heier Can you maybe suggest an edit with the code for sorting by FullName?

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is that if there is no space in the file name the name does not change. This is not supported by `Rename-Item`. You should use `Move-Item` instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace(" ", "_") }
```

Additionally, in your answer you missed the underscore in `$_.replace(...)` plus you where replacing spaces with an empty string. Included this in my answer.

Comment: Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
At line:1 char:58
+ Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item <<<<  $_ $_.replace(" ", "_") }
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError:

Comment: @matandked See this answer `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ' '} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ' ','' }` found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520172

Comment: This is the one that helped me understand that a filter is needed to make sure the name is changed, otherwise you get errors if trying to rename an object to the same name

Answer (score 1):

Adding a filter worked for me:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\path-to-directory -Recurse -Filter *foo* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace 'foo', 'bar'} -verbose
```