# Replace "." to "_" in folders using CMD

Tags: cmd

[image]

As can be seen in the image I have folders with "." in them I would like to replace these with a "_" using CMD is there a method to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace or delete certain characters from filenames of all files in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636996/replace-or-delete-certain-characters-from-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 1):

`cmd.exe` shell scripting is the worst approach for anything more than `@echo off` :-)

But ok.

You can use the enhanced shell command set to replace characters in a variable:

```
set DUH=FBB
echo %DUH:B=O%  -> FOO
```

So, for your problem, you need to read all folders and get them in a variable, so you can replace `.=_` and then rename.

First batch: `rena.cmd` iterates over your folders

```
@echo off
for /D %%i in ( *.* ) do call rena2.cmd %%i
```

Second batch: `rena2.cmd` handles the rename

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set TONAME=%~1

move %1 "%TONAME:.=_%"

exit /B
```

This can be done in one script, feel free to fiddle it together, I won't :-)

Comment: CMD scripting has its place, and is respectable for the proper purpose.

Comment: If you call a label instead of a second file you don;t need to worry if the files is moved to another location.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*.*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "dirname=%%a"
 SET "dirname=!dirname:.=_!"
 IF "!dirname!" neq "%%a" ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!dirname!"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Dimply perform a directory-list, change the `.` to `_` and if a change was made, perform the rename.

Comment: I normally used a CALL and label in the FOR body to keep the code clean, but as long as the env variables hold the correct value, then you are good.