# Replace certain characters from filenames in all files in a folder and his sub-folders

Tags: powershell, cmd, window, filenames

How can I change some character (#,%,&,$) in the filename of multiple files in one folder and his sub-folders?

Ravi Thapliyal answer how to do that with PowerShell but just for the files in a specific folder ([Replace or delete certain characters from filenames of all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636996/replace-or-delete-certain-characters-from-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder#16638371)).

I need to generalize that for all files in all folders in the selected one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own answer will only change one char, here is a solution with an array RegEx in one go, remove the chars you want to keep from $replace.

```
[char[]]$replace = '!@#$%^&*(){}[]":;,<>/|\+=`~ '''
$regex = ($replace | % {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

Get-ChildItem -recurse | 
  ForEach { 
    if ($_.Name -match $RegEx){
      Ren $_.Fullname -NewName $($_.Name -replace $RegEx, '_') -whatif
    } 
  }
```

If the output looks ok, remove the `-whatif`

**Edit** removed `-File` option from Get-ChildItem as it requires a recent Powershell version and wasn't necessary.

**Edit2** I regularly state that `Rename-Item` accepts piped input, so here is a more straight forward version:

```
[char[]]$replace = '!@#$%^&*(){}[]":;,<>/|\+=`~ '''
$regex = ($replace | % {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
Get-ChildItem -recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -match $RegEx} |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $RegEx, '_'} -whatif
```

Comment: Works perfect, after removing -whatif

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433764) from [Dustin Malone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5605601):

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace(" ", "_") }
```

It gives an error but do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The task can also be accomplished by a Windows `cmd` script ([batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)) -- however, there are some limitations, unless appropriate work-arounds are implemented.

The following script replaces `#`, `%`, `&`, `$`, `(` and `)` in file names. You can add more characters except `^`, `!`, `=` and `~`, which cannot be processed (an `if` query lets the replacement be skipped in order to avoid syntax errors). If you provide characters with a code greater than `127` = `0x7F`, you may probably need to switch the code page adequately (see the [`chcp`](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) command). Note that **the script does not rename any files** but only displays them, **until you remove the upper-case `ECHO` command**:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\path\to\root\dir" & rem /* (assign `%~1` here instead for the script to
                                  rem    accept the root dir. as command line argument) */
set _CHAR="#" "%%" "&" "$" "(" ")" & rem // (a `%` sign needs to be doubled!)
set "_REPL=_" & rem // (replacement character or string; this may also be empty)

if not defined _ROOT set "_ROOT=."
for /R "%_ROOT%" %%F in ("*.*") do (
    set "FILE=%%~F"
    set "NAME=%%~nxF"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%C in (!_CHAR!) do (
        if not "%%~C"=="^" if not "%%~C"=="!" if not "%%~C"=="=" if not "%%~C"=="~" (
            set "NAME=!NAME:%%~C=%_REPL%!"
        )
    )
    ECHO ren "!FILE!" "!NAME!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

To replace also the characters `^` and `!`, the script needs to be extended a bit:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\path\to\root\dir" & rem /* (assign `%~1` here instead for the script to
                                  rem    accept the root dir. as command line argument) */
set _CHAR="#" "%%" "&" "$" "(" ")" "^" "!" & rem // (a `%` sign needs to be doubled!)
set "_REPL=_" & rem // (replacement character or string; this may also be empty)

if not defined _ROOT set "_ROOT=."
for /R "%_ROOT%" %%F in ("*.*") do (
    set "FILE=%%~F"
    set "NAME=%%~nxF"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%C in (!_CHAR!) do (
        if "%%~C"=="^" (
            set "NAME=!NAME:^=^^!"
            call set "NAME=%%NAME:^=%_REPL%%%"
        ) else if "%%~C"=="!" (
            call set "NAME=%%NAME:^!=%_REPL%%%"
        ) else if not "%%~C"=="=" if not "%%~C"=="~" (
            set "NAME=!NAME:%%~C=%_REPL%!"
        )
    )
    ECHO ren "!FILE!" "!NAME!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

To replace also the characters `=` and `~`, the script needs to be extended much more:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\path\to\root\dir" & rem /* (assign `%~1` here instead for the script to
                                  rem    accept the root dir. as command line argument) */
set _CHAR="#" "%%" "&" "$" "(" ")" "^" "!" "=" "~" & rem // (a `%` sign needs to be doubled!)
set "_REPL=_" & rem // (replacement character or string; this may also be empty)

set "$LEN="
if not defined _ROOT set "_ROOT=."
for /R "%_ROOT%" %%F in ("*.*") do (
    set "FILE=%%~F"
    set "NAME=%%~nxF"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%C in (!_CHAR!) do (
        if "%%~C"=="^" (
            set "NAME=!NAME:^=^^!"
            call set "NAME=%%NAME:^=%_REPL%%%"
        ) else if "%%~C"=="!" (
            call set "NAME=%%NAME:^!=%_REPL%%%"
        ) else if "%%~C"=="~" (
            call :FAST NAME NAME "%%~C" "%_REPL%"
        ) else if "%%~C"=="=" (
            call :SLOW NAME NAME "%%~C" "%_REPL%"
        ) else (
            set "NAME=!NAME:%%~C=%_REPL%!"
        )
    )
    ECHO ren "!FILE!" "!NAME!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B


:FAST  rtn_string  ref_string  val_char  val_repl
rem // This works for `~` and `*`, but NOT for `=`!
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "STR="
set "CHR=%~3"
if not defined CHR goto :FQUIT
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "CHR=!CHR:~,1!"
set "STR=!%~2!"
:FLOOP
if defined STR (
    set "END=!STR:*%~3=!"
    if not "!END!"=="!STR!" (
        for /F "eol=%CHR% delims=%CHR%" %%L in ("!STR!") do (
            for /F "delims=" %%K in (^""!END!"^") do (
                endlocal
                set "STR=%%L%~4%%~K"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        goto :FLOOP
    )
)
:FQUIT
for /F "delims=" %%K in (^""!STR!"^") do (
    endlocal
    set "STR=%%~K"
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%STR%"
exit /B


:SLOW  rtn_string  ref_string  val_char  val_repl
rem // This works even for `=`.
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "STR="
set "CHR=%~3"
set "RPL=%~4"
if not defined CHR goto :SQUIT
if not defined $LEN call :LEN $LEN RPL
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "CHR=!CHR:~,1!"
set "STR=!%~2!"
set /A "IDX=0"
:SLOOP
set /A "NXT=IDX+1"
if defined STR (
    set "POS=!STR:~%IDX%,1!"
    if defined POS (
        if "!POS!"=="!CHR!" (
            set "STR=!STR:~,%IDX%!!RPL!!STR:~%NXT%!"
            set /A "NXT=IDX+$LEN"
        )
        set /A "IDX=NXT"
        goto :SLOOP
    )
)
:SQUIT
for /F "delims=" %%K in (^""!STR!"^") do (
    endlocal
    set "STR=%%~K"
    set "$LEN=%$LEN%"
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%STR%" & set "$LEN=%$LEN%"
exit /B


:LEN  rtn_length  ref_string
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STR=!%~2!"
if not defined STR (set /A LEN=0) else (set /A LEN=1)
for %%L in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if defined STR (
        set "INT=!STR:~%%L!"
        if not "!INT!"=="" set /A LEN+=%%L & set "STR=!INT!"
    )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%LEN%"
exit /B
```