# Replace "." with "_" in file name

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to replace pdf file names:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\All -Filter *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('.','_') }
```

It works fine if I replace `%20` to `_`, but if we use "test.one.pdf", I need "test_one.pdf" as output, if I use above syntax it replaces the . before pdf like "test_one_pdf".

Comment: @4c74356b41 He doesn't use regex, anyhow I don't see a reason why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code will rename `name.001.pdf` to `name_001_pdf`, so unless you actually want to remove the extensions of your files you need to replace only within the files name and not the extension.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\All" -Filter "*.pdf" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Replace(".","_") + $_.Extension }
```