# bulk renaming files using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bunch of files (and more coming) that are downloaded from the internet (pdf printed) but they do come with a lot of names that I do not need/want; so I want to have a text file with the things that I want to remove. example
I have a text file with this two lines

```
Chapter 13. Text and Regular Expressions - Master-PowerShell _ With Dr. Tobias Weltner - PowerShell.com
- PowerShell Scripts, Tips, Forums, and Resources.htm
```

I want to keep adding lines of text to that file and then call it from another batch file to remove all the lines that are in this file, I got something working that I took from foxidrive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636996/replace-or-delete-certain-characters-from-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder)

I could keep adding strings to the rename, but I'm wondering if I could get all the lines to remove from a text file, and I know that there are programs out there (free ones) to do that, but I'd rather use the good old DOS batch.
Thanks

Here is my code

```
@echo off
if Exist %CD%/temp.txt del %CD%/temp.txt
echo @echo off >%CD%/temp.txt
echo for /f "delims=" %%%%a in ('dir /a:-d /o:n /b') do call :next "%%%%a" >>%CD%/temp.txt
echo GOTO:EOF >>%CD%/temp.txt
echo :next >>%CD%/temp.txt
echo set "newname=%%~nx1" >>%CD%/temp.txt
Echo.>>%CD%/temp.txt
for /f "delims=" %%l in (%CD%\To_remove.txt) Do (
echo set "newname=%%newname:%%l=%%">> %CD%\temp.txt)
Echo.>>%CD%/temp.txt
echo ren %%1 "%%newname%%" >>%CD%/temp.txt
Start Temp.txt
Exit
```

I did save it as txt and opened at the end of script to see how it looks, it's just a matter of renaming it to .cmd and works.
I had to add comments and edit my post to add it all together but works
Thanks

Comment: Let me clarify I have a bunch of files downloaded from internet, you can create fake files with real names using all this in a text file  
Batch File Rename with Windows PowerShell.htm
No More Lonely Nights Chords (ver 2) by Paul McCartney @ Ultimate-Guitar.Com.htm
save it as Fake_Files.txt
run this batch file
    For /F "tokens=*" %%G in (Fake_Files.txt) do Echo>%%G
After that I wanted to write another text file that will contain 
 _ PowerShell content from Windows IT Pro
 @ Ultimate-Guitar.Com
 _ Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog
all that saved as a text file with the name To_remove.txt

Comment: and finally a script that will take all the lines in To_remove.txt and rename all the files in the folder removing the text that is in To_remove.txt.
Found the solution and I'm posting it here just in case somebody could use it, it's a mix of two post one found here and the other I do not remember
here is my batch