# Rename subfolders recursively

Tags: powershell, recursion, file-rename

I have been given a task to remove spaces in file and folder names for 1 TB worth of data. I have test files and folders on a laptop I am using.

I can get all the top-level folders and files to remove the spaces from the names. However, I'm not sure how to get it to go into all subfolders and keep going.

The code I am using is :

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\users\admin2\desktop\ProjectTest" |
         Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ' ','' }
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace names of all directiories and files in PS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518518/replace-names-of-all-directiories-and-files-in-ps)